# $scope variables, ng-hide/show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I am missing something about $scope. I have some ng-hide/shows that have a variable in a top nav. Inside an ng-view that are being linked to controllers via the app config function. My nav code is in "NavController". But I have a page in a view outside of the nav that is linked to "AppointmentController" running that code that takes care of setting an appointment. After you have gone through some steps, you are able to login, this code is inside of the AppointmentController view but I have done this -

EDIT - I just realized, the input below does have to be in a seperate controller. When I attach it to NavController, I am wanting the apptLogin() to change the main view data which is all in a seperate controller.

```
<input ng-controller="NavController" ng-click="apptLogin(email)" value="Login and Continue" class="btn btn-default pull-left" >

$scope.apptLogin = function(email){
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {email: email},
    url: '/common_includes/ajax/validateUser.php',
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      if(response.data.status == 0){
        var login_message = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+response.data.message+'</div>';
        $('#login_modal .modal-body').html(login_message);
        $('#login_modal').modal();
        $interval(function(){
          $('#login_modal').modal('hide');
        }, 1400, 1);
      }
      if(response.data.status == 1){
        $scope.appt_history = true;
        console.log($scope);
        var login_message = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'+response.data.message+'</div>';
        $('#login_modal .modal-body').html(login_message);
        $('#login_modal').modal();
        $interval(function(){
          $scope.click_login = false;
          $('#login_modal').modal('hide');
        }, 1400, 1);
      }
```

The code all runs. This line here is what should toggle the hide/show but it is not. -

```
$scope.appt_history = true;
```

If I am confused though because if console.log($scope) after the above line, I see all the NavController variables, and $scope.appt_history does == true, yet hide/show not changing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Thus you fixed the problem now?

Comment: No...I have items in this nav that are all attached to one controller...I thought everything would take place in that area. But now I need a button that is attached to another controller to change a show/hide variable that is in the nav controller. Basically, two controllers with different scopes. I know this should maybe be done with a "service" but not sure how to use it in this particular case.

Comment: Just as an aside, using JQuery to show/hide stuff can lead to weird scoping issues in angular.  You might need to `$scope.$apply` a lot of stuff to get things into angular's scope.  I suggest using custom directives for modals or UI Bootstrap since it wraps a lot of that JQuery into a angular-ready form.

Comment: Yes, I usually don't use Jquery to hide/show in angular. Those are the built in jquery modal functions that come with Bootstrap. I usually just cheat in Angular and use the Bootstrap JS for modals. Haven't had any problems for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to inject $rootScope into both controllers and place the shared data properties there instead of in $scope, but this is not the recommended way of doing things.

HOWEVER, I recommend using a service instead.  They are simple to write, and make sharing data across controllers a breeze without having to resort to polluting the root scope.

Basically, you first create your service and add the property that you want to share to its constructor

```
app.service('sharingSvc', function() {
  this.sharedValue = 'initialized';
});
```

Now, you can inject that service into the controllers that require access to your shared property.

```
app.controller('pageOneCtrl', function($scope, sharingSvc) {
  $scope.pageOneSare = sharingSvc;
});
```

[Here is a complete, but very basic Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vl8BYGNxgpF16EPlg9Fa?p=preview) that shows how to share data across multiple controllers and views using a service.  This should be enough to get you started.  Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Looks good. I have used services to send data back and forth from a database many times, but that is all I have used them for yet. I will give this a try and post my code. Thank you.